how to make a Speed-meter without a progressbar
I have a proyect to make a speedTest with a speed-meter o tachmeter fuctional in real time,but i can't found a library with explain examples for how to used....
I tried with a progress bar to indicate how the Wi-Fi speed was going up or down. There are 3, one for the download, another for the upload, and the last one is for the ping, although the latter is unnecessary, but the idea is that the bar work in the time that the wifi speed is calculated
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import speedtest

class ProgressWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Toplevel()
        self.root.title("Progreso")
        self.root.geometry("300x100")

        self.status_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Espere, se está calculando...", font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.status_label.pack(pady=20)

    def update_status(self, status):
        self.status_label.config(text=status)
        self.root.update()

    def close(self):
        self.root.destroy()

class SpeedTestApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("SpeedTest App")
        self.root.geometry("400x350")

        # Variables para los resultados
        self.ping_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.download_var = tk.DoubleVar()  # Usamos DoubleVar para valores decimales
        self.upload_var = tk.DoubleVar()    # Usamos DoubleVar para valores decimales
        self.status_var = tk.StringVar()

        # Estado inicial del botón
        self.button_state = 'normal'

        # Crear la interfaz
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Título
        title_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="SpeedTest", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        title_label.pack(pady=10)

        # Botón de inicio
        self.start_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Start", command=self.start_speedtest)
        self.start_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Etiquetas y velocímetros de Descarga
        download_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Velocidad de Descarga (Mbps)")
        download_label.pack()
        self.download_value_label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.download_var)
        self.download_value_label.pack()
        self.download_progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, length=200, mode="determinate", variable=self.download_var)
        self.download_progressbar.pack(pady=5)

        # Etiquetas y velocímetros de Subida
        upload_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Velocidad de Subida (Mbps)")
        upload_label.pack()
        self.upload_value_label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.upload_var)
        self.upload_value_label.pack()
        self.upload_progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, length=200, mode="determinate", variable=self.upload_var)
        self.upload_progressbar.pack(pady=5)

        # Etiqueta y campo de Ping
        ping_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Ping (ms)")
        ping_label.pack()
        self.ping_value_label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.ping_var)
        self.ping_value_label.pack(pady=5)
        self.ping_progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, length=200, mode="determinate", variable=self.ping_var)
        self.ping_progressbar.pack(pady=5)

        # Mensaje de estado
        self.status_label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.status_var, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.status_label.pack(pady=10)

    def start_speedtest(self):
        # Deshabilitar el botón de inicio mientras se realiza la prueba
        self.start_button.config(state='disabled')
        self.button_state = 'disabled'

        # Mostrar la ventana de progreso
        self.progress_window = ProgressWindow()

        # Ejecutar el test de velocidad en un hilo separado para no bloquear la UI
        threading.Thread(target=self.run_speedtest).start()

    def run_speedtest(self):
        # Actualizar el mensaje de estado y mostrarlo en la ventana de progreso
        self.progress_window.update_status("Espere, se está calculando...")

        st = speedtest.Speedtest()
        st.get_best_server()

        # Realizar la prueba de velocidad
        download_speed = st.download() / 1_000_000  # Convertir a Mbps
        upload_speed = st.upload() / 1_000_000      # Convertir a Mbps
        ping = st.results.ping

        # Actualizar la UI con los resultados
        self.ping_var.set(round(ping, 2))
        self.ping_value_label.config(text=f"{ping:.2f} ms")
        self.download_var.set(round(download_speed, 2))
        self.upload_var.set(round(upload_speed, 2))

        # Al final de la prueba, guardar los resultados en un archivo (opcional)
        resultados = {
            'timestamp': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'ping': ping,
            'download_speed': download_speed,
            'upload_speed': upload_speed
        }
        guardar_resultados(resultados)

        # Cerrar la ventana de progreso y actualizar el mensaje de estado en la ventana principal
        self.progress_window.update_status("Prueba completada")
        self.progress_window.close()

        # Actualizar el mensaje de estado en la ventana principal
        self.status_var.set("Prueba completada")

        # Habilitar nuevamente el botón de inicio para permitir más pruebas
        self.start_button.config(state='normal')
        self.button_state = 'normal'

    def disable_button(self):
        self.start_button.config(state='disabled')

def guardar_resultados(resultados, filename='historial.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'a') as file:
        file.write(f"{resultados['timestamp']}, {resultados['ping']}, {resultados['download_speed']:.2f}, {resultados['upload_speed']:.2f}\n")
    print("Resultados guardados en el archivo:", filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = SpeedTestApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

have a better way of doing it since, I want a speedometer instead of the progress bar. so that it gives a better appearance to the program since this is just the interface???

Well, if you want to have a speedometer “widget”, you will have to implement it yourself. You will need to use the canvas widget to draw it

oh thats posibble but, if i use the canvas widget to draw it, i can realize the speedometer with a animation like that "https://gifer.com/en/dJv", because I am interested if it is possible through that image to move the tick based on the reading like the ookla program, thats my problem for this moment, well doesn't matter, thanks for the recommendation :)

Basically, you just need to know math (circle theory) to implement this behavior. If you want, I can send you a draft of the speedometer I made, but I think it is far from perfect. Or is your main problem with calculating the internet speed runtime rather than the speedometer itself?

i thanks for the recommendation, but i finally get it, in the same librarie of wxPython has a superclass for update the paint with events into the program the lib call wx.lib.newevent, withs i can do the animation :)

Let's start with the import of libraries and the start of SuperClass to update the drawing
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM
import wx.lib.newevent
import os
import threading
import time
import math
from datetime import datetime
import speedtest

Evento personalizado para actualizar los frames
UpdateEvent, EVT_UPDATE = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

SuperClase para actualizar el dibujo
class BufferedWindow(wx.Window):
def __init__(self, parent, id=-1, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, 
    size=wx.DefaultSize):
    wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size)
    self.buffer = wx.Bitmap(1, 1)  # Bitmap inicial pequeño
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

def OnSize(self, event):
    size = self.GetClientSize()
    self.buffer = wx.Bitmap(size.GetWidth(), size.GetHeight())
    self.InitBuffer()
    self.Refresh()
    event.Skip()

metodo de actualizacion que permite que el dibujo este en movimiento
def InitBuffer(self):
    dc = wx.MemoryDC(self.buffer)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
    dc.Clear()
    self.Draw(dc)

def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer)

def Draw(self, dc):
    pass

now this is the class that allows us to draw the speedometer, the design is the simplest since in the call for the speedometer the libraries are invoked for the style
class SpeedMeterBufferedWindow(BufferedWindow):
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
    BufferedWindow.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)
    self.speed = 0
#Here to defined design of speedometer

    self.meter = SM.SpeedMeter(self, agwStyle=wx.lib.agw.speedmeter.SM_DRAW_HAND | wx.lib.agw.speedmeter.SM_DRAW_SECTORS | wx.lib.agw.speedmeter.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS | wx.lib.agw.speedmeter.SM_DRAW_PARTIAL_FILLER | wx.lib.agw.speedmeter.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT)
    self.meter.SetAngleRange(-math.pi / 6, 7 * math.pi / 6)
    self.Bind(EVT_UPDATE, self.OnUpdate)
    self.InitUI()

#Metodo proactivo como lo dice UI es User Interface en el cual es el metodo para para darle el diseño a los velocimetros y al programa
def InitUI(self):
    self.meter.SetSpeedBackground(wx.Colour(255, 255, 100))
    self.meter.SetHandColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 255))
    self.meter.SetMiddleText("Mbps")
    self.meter.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.BLACK)
    self.meter.SetFillerColour(wx.RED)
    
    intervals = range(0, 200, 50)
    self.meter.SetIntervals(intervals)
    ticks = [str(interval) for interval in intervals]
    self.meter.SetTicks(ticks)
    self.meter.SetTicksColour(wx.BLACK)
    self.meter.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(5)
    self.meter.SetSpeedValue(0)

def Draw(self, dc):
    size = self.GetClientSize()
    self.meter.SetSize(size.GetWidth(), size.GetHeight())
    self.meter.Draw(dc)

def OnUpdate(self, event):
    self.meter.SetSpeedValue(self.speed)
    self.InitBuffer()
    self.Refresh()

def SetSpeed(self, speed):
    self.speed = speed
    wx.PostEvent(self, UpdateEvent())

All that remains is the class for the user interface of the application, that is, if you don't do it like I did, I put it all in a single code, I recommend that you do it in separate files.
class SpeedTestFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(SpeedTestFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    self.InitUI()

def InitUI(self):
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    
    # Encabezado de texto
    header = wx.StaticText(panel, label="SpeedTester", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    font = wx.Font(18, wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
    header.SetFont(font)
    header.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(wx.BLUE))
    vbox.Add(header, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.TOP, border=20)
    # SpeedMeter for Download
    self.downloadMeter = SpeedMeterBufferedWindow(panel, size=(300, 200))
    self.downloadMeter.meter.SetMiddleText("Descarga Mbps")
    vbox.Add(self.downloadMeter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)

    # SpeedMeter for Upload
    self.uploadMeter = SpeedMeterBufferedWindow(panel, size=(300, 200))
    self.uploadMeter.meter.SetMiddleText("Subida Mbps")
    vbox.Add(self.uploadMeter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)

    self.startBtn = wx.Button(panel, label='Comenzar Testeo')
    self.startBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)
    vbox.Add(self.startBtn, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=10)

    panel.SetSizer(vbox)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

    self.SetSize((400, 600))
    self.SetTitle('Speed Test')
    self.Centre()

        
def OnStart(self, event):
    self.startBtn.Disable()
    self.downloadMeter.SetSpeed(0)
    self.uploadMeter.SetSpeed(0)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.RunSpeedTest)
    thread.start()

something of backend, is the speedmeter librarie for the analize the data of the wifi
    def RunSpeedTest(self):
    try:
        st = speedtest.Speedtest()
        st.download()  # Warm up
        download_speed = st.download() / 1_000_000  # Convert to Mbps
        upload_speed = st.upload() / 1_000_000  # Convert to Mbps
        ping = st.results.ping

        self.UpdateMeters(download_speed, upload_speed, ping)
        self.LogResults(download_speed, upload_speed, ping)

    except Exception as e:
        wx.CallAfter(wx.MessageBox, f'Error: {str(e)}', 'Error', wx.ICON_ERROR)

    wx.CallAfter(self.startBtn.Enable)

def UpdateMeters(self, download_speed, upload_speed, ping):
    for i in range(10):  # Actualizar 10 veces (1 vez por segundo)
        wx.CallAfter(self.downloadMeter.SetSpeed, (i + 0.5) * (download_speed / 10))
        wx.CallAfter(self.uploadMeter.SetSpeed, (i + 0.5) * (upload_speed / 10))
        time.sleep(1)
    wx.CallAfter(wx.MessageBox, f'Download: {download_speed:.2f} Mbps\nUpload: {upload_speed:.2f} Mbps\nPing: {ping} ms', 'Speed Test Results', wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

def LogResults(self, download_speed, upload_speed, ping):
    # Obtener la ruta del directorio actual (carpeta frontend)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Navegar a la carpeta backend
    data_folder = os.path.join(current_dir, '..', 'backend')
    config_file = os.path.join(data_folder, 'historial.txt')

    # Escribir los resultados en el archivo historial.txt
    with open(config_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(f"{datetime.now()}: Download: {download_speed:.2f} Mbps, Upload: {upload_speed:.2f} Mbps, Ping: {ping} ms\n")

def OnClose(self, event):
    self.Destroy()

The code works, so other people may be able to use it as an example, although it is not the best example, but it serves as a basis for something more practical, that my gift to the community
